# How do I forward/redirect all requests from HTTP to HTTPS in NancyFX SelfHost?

Tags: http, redirect, https, nancy, self-hosting

I'm trying to get it so that any requests made to:

`http://<myserver>:1234`

are redirected to:

`https://<myserver>:1234`

I've tried using "this.RequiresHttps()" in modules, but when I hit the url `http://<myserver>:1234`, the browser just spins, and I'm guessing it's because I didn't construct `NancyHost` with an HTTP URI.  I can't add the HTTP URI to NancyHost along with the HTTPS URI like so:

`var host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:1234"), new Uri("https://localhost:1234"));`

because I'll get registration conflicts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant have http and https listening on the same port. Change the port for your https binding, and specify it in your RequiresHttps call.

Comment: If that's the case, how is it that some sites operate like that?  I access the same port with HTTP then get redirected to HTTPS version with the same port.

Comment: They don't ;) if you don't see a port specified then its 443.

Comment: You will also need to bind the cert to the url reservation, have you done that? This is standard http.sys / httplistener stuff btw, not Nancy specific.

Comment: Hah, so I went back to an internal site to double check because it had been awhile, and yes you are right they are just doing 80 to 443 :(  Kind of sucks.  You'd think there would be a way to read in the request and redirect to the other protocol.  I'm obviously ignorant in this department.  To answer your other question, yes I have bound the certificate to the port using netsh.  SSL stuff works fine.

Comment: Different protocols, different ports, that's just the way it works.